# Does $(\neg R\to R)\to R$ give rise to a proof strategy?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Take for example proof by contradiction, it can be viewed as a certain deduction in logic which can be used outside of logic to prove many interesting propositions.

My question is: can we use $(\neg R\to R)\to R$ as a similar strategy?

Comment: The difficulty is finding propositions $R$ such that $\neg R\to R$ can be proved more easily than $R$ can be proved directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be,

Let me give you an example from group theory,

lemma 1:$P$ group can not have trivial center.

lemma 2: if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.

Claim:Any group with order $p^2$ is abelian where p is prime.

Proof:Assume G is  nonabelian group with order $p^2$ then $Z(G)$ is proper group.
By lemma1;$Z(G)$ is nontrivial $\implies$ $|Z(G)|=p$ $\implies G/Z(G)$ is cylic $\implies$ G is abelian.

As a result, ($G$ is nonabelian $\implies $ $G$ is abelian) $\implies$ $G$ is abelian.