# Is this a proof by contradiction?

Tags: group-theory, logic, finite-groups, proof-writing, abelian-groups

Below is a proof that any group of order $p^2$ is abelian $(p$ prime of course).

> Let $Z \left({G}\right)$ be the center of $G$. We know $|Z(G)|>1$. $\color{blue}{\text{Suppose}} \left\vert{Z \left({G}\right)}\right\vert = p$.
>
> Then $|G/ Z(G)|=p\Rightarrow G/Z(G)$ is cyclic. It is not hard to then show that $G$ is abelian, $\color{blue}{\text{therefore}}$ $Z(G)=p^2$. This is a contradiction.

I fully understand the proof, but the logic seems strange to me; mainly, I can't decide whether this is an actual proof by contradiction or whether it is disguised as one. What is actually happening here, in terms of logic?

Comment: Of course it is a proof by contradiction. In a proof by contradiction you get to an absurd. In principle, once you get to an absurd you can derive any other proposition, including the thesis of the statement you wanted to prove in the first place.

Comment: Please check this; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576482/does-neg-r-to-r-to-r-give-rise-to-a-proof-strategy/576524#576524

Comment: Perhaps the one general *important* thing that can be taken from  (the proof of a part of) this is: for **any** group $\;G\;$ , the quotient $\;G/Z(G)\;$ cannot be cyclic *non-trivial* .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof *as written* is a proof by contradiction. Logically, the proof is fundamentally a proof by cases: because $Z(G)$ is a subgroup, we have that $|Z(G)|$ is $1$, $p$, or $p^2$. The case $|Z(G)| = 1$ is eliminated by a separate result, and $|Z(G)| = p^2$ is the desired result, so the proof proceeds by contradiction: assume $|Z(G)| = p$ (which is what we *don't* want to happen) and derive a contradiction.

This is not to say that *every* proof of this result must proceed by contradiction. At the cost of using some slightly more advanced facts, it is possible to write a proof that is not (directly) a proof by contradiction:

> We know (as before) that $Z(G)$ is nontrivial. Let $h$ be any nonidentity element in the $Z(G)$. If $\langle h \rangle = G$ we are done. Otherwise, $|h| = p$. Then $\langle h \rangle$ is normal, since $h \in Z(G)$, and $|G / \langle h \rangle | = p$. Thus $G / \langle h\rangle$ is cyclic. Then, because $\langle h \rangle \subseteq Z(G)$, $G / Z(G)$ is a quotient group of $G / \langle h \rangle$, and so $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic. But that implies (by another theorem) that $G$ is abelian, as desired.

In this proof, we did not assume $|Z(G)| = p$, so there is no direct contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the lemma is corallary of the following lemma;

**Lemma:** $H\leq Z(G)\leq K\leq G$ and $K/H$ is cyclic then $K$ is abelian.

**Corallary$1$:** In particular, we can take $H=Z(G)$ and $K=G$ and we can say that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.

**Corallary$2$:** By corallry $1$, $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic if and only if $G/Z(G)$ is trivial.

But many books does not mention **lemma$1$** and **corallray$2$**, so the proof may seem to be strange. But if we use **corallary$2$**, we can say "proof by contradiction". But if we do not use it, it is still a valid way but I think it has no name,since the logic path like **$(\neg R\to R)\to R$**.

I also suggest you you to check;

[Does $(\neg R\to R)\to R$ give rise to a proof strategy?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576482/does-neg-r-to-r-to-r-give-rise-to-a-proof-strategy/576524#576524)